# Missing "Prax Zoa" and "Phyta" research

Tags: achievements, waking-mars

There are two research entries that I am missing:

- The "diet" entry of **Prax Zoa**
- The last entry in **Phyta** just labeled "Research Pending"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are both unlocked by feeding a **Feran Seed** to each of the creatures.

If you throw a Feran Seed too hard it will hit the wall and explode, killing the creature. The key is to throw the seed *very carefully* by having the cursor as close to your character as possible before throwing it.

[image: Waking Mars: Throw the Feran Seed carefully by keeping the cursor close to the player]